# Syntax - Range.SpecialCells Method VBA

Tags: vba, excel, range

By using the Range.SpecialCells Method (Excel), is it possible to select cells containing a text "abc" within a range ? I am not understanding the syntax... in the link below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx

```
sub sub1()

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Worksheets("worksheet").Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, "abc")
```

> not working

```
Set rng = Worksheets("Output-Booth").Range("C18:C500").Find(What:="abc")
```

> not working

```
rng.Rows.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
```

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** to add the code to store filtered cells instead of deleting them

`Specialcells()` don't expose the behavior you're asking for

you'd better use `AutoFilter()`

---

code to delete cells with given text entire row

```
Sub sub1()
    With Worksheets("worksheet").Range("A1:A10") '<--| reference your range
       .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="abc" '<--| filter referenced cells with "abc"
       If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp  '<--| if any filtered cells other than header then delete filtered cells skipping header
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove filtering
    End With
End Sub
```

be sure row 1 is the header one

---

code to "store" cells with given text criteria into a `range`

```
Sub sub2()
    Dim rng As Range

    With Worksheets("worksheet").Range("A1:A10") '<--| reference your range
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="abc" '<--| filter referenced cells with "abc"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then Set rng = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| if any filtered cells other than header then set 'rng' to filtered cells skipping header
         .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False '<--| remove filtering
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - how can I store in the range "rng", the cells from another range with a text string criteria?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you: please be more specific

Comment: see edited answer. if I solved your _original_ question please mark answer as accepted, thank you!